# Is there a Cardano Quickstart Application?

Tags: nami-wallet, learning, webapp

Me and my team are searching for a quickstart project for Cardano, such that we can start from such a project, understand its architecture, and evolve the base project into a real-life product.

So far, we've found only courses, eg. the Plutus Pioneers Program from IOG or the Gimbalabs Project-Based Learning. But none of the two above is a quickstart that enable us to Quickly have a running application and understand its mechanics.

Details

An example of what we would expect in a simple working application would be the following:

- A simple contract (e.g. Gift: someone locks funds, someone else gets the locked funds)
- A simple application backend that can run on localhost
- A simple integration with Nami wallet to send the funds

Answer (score 1):

There are a few example contracts in plutus-apps repo. [AlwaysSucceeds](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/blob/main/plutus-example/src/PlutusExample/AlwaysSucceeds.hs) is the simplest, allowing one to lock funds and another to unlock them. Make sure to check the [spending script documentation](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/blob/main/doc/plutus/howtos/plutus-spending-script-example.rst) to help with that.

The same repo also has a demo of the Plutus Application Backend (PAB) running locally and integrated with Nami to send some funds. See [PAB-Nami simple demo](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/tree/main/plutus-pab-executables/demo/pab-nami).